# Is there an expected result attribute in xUnit?

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I started working with `xUnit` and I have a question.
Let's say I'm testing a function that receives an `int` and returns `true` if the parameter is greater than 10.
I know that I could do this:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(7)]
[InlineData(13)]
[InlineData(4)]
public void MyTest(int num)
{
    bool res = MyCompMethod(num);
    Assert.True(res);
}
```

But it doesn't seem good enough because it will show that some of the tests have failed, although they didn't.  I want to enter the expected result as well, so I could compare the values, something like:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(7), false]
[InlineData(13), true]
[InlineData(4), false]
```

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't such attribute, but you could do this instead:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(7, false)]
[InlineData(13, true)]
[InlineData(4, false)]
public void MyTest(int num, bool shouldBeGreaterThanTen)
{
    bool isGreaterThanTen = MyCompMethod(num);
    Assert.Equal(shouldBeGreaterThanTen, isGreaterThanTen);
}
```

Comment: that last parameter should ideally be called `expected`

Comment: The parameters in `[InlineData(4, false)]` just have to match the test signature so you could just name it `(int num, bool expected)`. It allows you to put in more than just a single data value with an expected result. You could imagine how you could test if adding two numbers together matches an expected result.